# Selenium Webdriver fails to load browser through WebDriverManager

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, chromedriver

We can run our tests in different browsers in selenium Webdriver, previously we need to executable files to run our test in any browser. But now we can achieve without using exe files & with the help of WebDriverManager following below syntax to open chrome browser.

```
 WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();
 driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

**Driver class I have defined below code:**

```
public static WebDriver getDriver(){
        try{
            if(driver == null) {

        /*    PropertiesFileReader obj=new PropertiesFileReader(); 
            Properties properties=obj.getproperty();
            openBrowser(properties.getProperty("browserName"), properties.getProperty("URL")); */
                WebDriverManager.iedriver().setup();
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

I have login page and logintestcase, I am calling `getDriver()` method from logintest class using below code:

```
public LoginPage loginpage=PageFactory.initElements(Driver.getDriver(), LoginPage.class);
```

**But I am getting exception :**

```
   SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:843)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:135)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
```

and same code is working with `.exe` files but not when we are loading through WebDriverManager.

Comment: your test failed just because you are using `iedriver().setup();` which is used for *IE Browser* but below you declare the instance of `ChromeDriver`.

Comment: The thing I am observed is chrome is updating quietly from behind most of the times if I change the chrome driver to updated version my program start working normally.

Answer (score 0):

Try this may this code help you-

```
 WebDriver driver;
public static WebDriver getDriver(){
        try{
            if(driver == null) {                
                WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
                driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return driver;
    }
```

If you want to add more capabilities in *webdrivermanager* try this too-

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver()
                 .version("2.40")
                 .arch32()
                 .proxy("myproxyhostname:80")
                 .proxyUser("myusername")
                 .proxyPass("myawesomePassword")
.setup();
```

Comment: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManagerException: chromedriver 66.0.3359.181 for WIN64 not found in http://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/chromedriver

Comment: You need to add following jar file in your classpath: `slf4j-simple-1.6.2.jar` and for chromedriver exception try to download the correct version by using `.Version()` capabilitiy of `WebDriverManager`.

Comment: nable to read VR Path Registry getting for firefoxdriver, refer ccode-- WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().version("0.21.0").setup();
  driver=new FirefoxDriver();

Comment: Is your chromeDriver working?

Comment: chrome is working perfectly

Comment: ok great, so it's your new question so i will suggest you to post new question for this.

Comment: Firefox is also working but last tcs failed it wont click on element and in IE it load the browser, sometimes it run whole scripts(one issue-opens in different tab) & sometimes it runs one-or two test cases

Comment: then may be your test case failed due to element's exceptions if it's able to open the browser perfectly and there is no `WebDriver` exception then you have your answer of your question